# What should be the right "commit type" from conventional commit?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, conventions, conventional-commits

I created a commit with the purpose to unhide a feature, the code change is to only uncomment some lines of code and show the feature, so now the feature will be displayed to the user.

Should this commit type be `feat` or `chore`?

I think it should be `chore` because it doesn‘t add the feature to the code, only allows it to be displayed, but from user POV it is a new feature, what is your opinion?

Comment: Personally I think I would make it `feat: activate feature X` because you are in fact functionally adding a feature, even though it's not in this commit that all the code got written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither, according *[Convential Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/)* you need `refactor`:

> A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature

More information about other *semantic commit types* you can read [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#type).

Most of the types can‘t be clearly assigned, and therefore have leeway and can also be used differently in the team, according to the specifications.

So this question *can‘t be answered definitively*, in general. Then in my team, for example, we only use `feat`, `fix` or `chore` as *commit-convention*. And if we unlock an already implemented feature (*feature-toggle*), a `feat`-commit message is created in the respective branch.